# VS2010 Unresolved External Symbol boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::throw_on_error when linking boost-system with a project using libtorrent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-asio, lnk2019, libtorrent

I'm trying to build a small command line BitTorrent client using Rasterbar's libtorrent, which depends on Boost.  I've built both the Boost libraries and the libtorrent library using their respective directions, but when I try to build my project I get the following linking errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MiniBT, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MiniBT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::throw_on_error(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &)" (?throw_on_error@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::detail::winsock_init<2,0>::winsock_init<2,0>(bool)" (??0?$winsock_init@$01$0A@@detail@asio@boost@@QAE@_N@Z)
1>MiniBT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?startup@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@EE@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::detail::winsock_init<2,0>::winsock_init<2,0>(bool)" (??0?$winsock_init@$01$0A@@detail@asio@boost@@QAE@_N@Z)
1>MiniBT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::asio::error::get_misc_category(void)" (?get_misc_category@error@asio@boost@@YAABVerror_category@system@3@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::asio::error::`dynamic initializer for 'misc_category''(void)" (??__Emisc_category@error@asio@boost@@YAXXZ)
1>MiniBT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl boost::asio::detail::win_tss_ptr_create(void)" (?win_tss_ptr_create@detail@asio@boost@@YAKXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::detail::win_tss_ptr<class boost::asio::detail::call_stack<class boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service,unsigned char>::context>::win_tss_ptr<class boost::asio::detail::call_stack<class boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service,unsigned char>::context>(void)" (??0?$win_tss_ptr@Vcontext@?$call_stack@Vwin_iocp_io_service@detail@asio@boost@@E@detail@asio@boost@@@detail@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>MiniBT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::cleanup(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &)" (?cleanup@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::detail::winsock_init<2,0>::~winsock_init<2,0>(void)" (??1?$winsock_init@$01$0A@@detail@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
```

It seems to indicate that the asio::detail namespace didn't get included in the boost-system library as it is only those 5 symbols that it seems to have a problem with and it is linking to the boost-system library just fine otherwise. I'm trying to build a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system, but everything I've checked seems to be correctly configured for this.

I know I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figure out what.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try defining BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION

Comment: I've tried both BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION and BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK and neither work.  the only difference is that the errors include __declspec(dllimport) in front of the function definitions when dyn_link is used.

Comment: How did you build libtorrent? which version of libtorrent are you using? it appears that you're not linking against the boost.asio library, which should have been built as part of libtorrent, in src/asio.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION defined, in addition to #include "boost/asio/ssl/impl/src.hpp", you must also #include "boost/asio/impl/src.hpp" in one of your cpp files.